# table in razor, rows dependant on database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a table with 7 rows and 27 columns. The highest column should be on the top of the table.

The model looks like this:

```
public partial class tblShelve
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } //For example B-01-07 means column 1, row 7
    public int capacity { get; set; } // I am using this to style the cells
    public int row { get; set; }
    public int column { get; set;}
}
```

My HomeController returns this:

```
private ScanningContext db = new ScanningContext();

// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.tblShelves
        .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("B"))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.column)
        .ThenBy(x => x.row)
        .ToList()
        );
}
```

And my Index.cshtml code looks like this

```
@model IEnumerable<Shelves_Visualisation.Models.tblShelve>
...
    <table>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                    if (item.name.StartsWith("B-01"))
                    {
                        @:<tr class="my-tr">
                        //old: <tr class="my-tr">
                    }

                    @switch (item.capacity)
                    {
                        case (0):
                            <td class="classic-height my-td empty">@item.name</td>
                            break;
                        case (50):
                            <td class="classic-height my-td half-full">@item.name</td>
                            break;
                        default:
                            <td class="classic-height my-td full">@item.name</td>
                            break;
                    }


                @if(item.name.StartsWith("B-27"))
                {
                    @:</tr>
                    //old: </tr>
                }
            }
    </table>
```

But it just creates an empty page. Visual Studio is telling me, that the `<tr>` element wasn't closed and the `</tr>` has no matching start tag. Any ideas how to fix this? (Response.Write is not an option, since it just puts the output to the beginning of the page outside of the `<body>` tag). Without the conditions on `<tr>` tag it works, so I know that the error must be somewhere there.

The result should look like this:
[image]

I got this from a static html, which I generated like this:

```
   <table>
        @for (int i = 7; i > 0; --i)
        {
            <tr>
                @for (int j = 1; j < 28; ++j)
            {
                switch (rnd.Next(0, 3))
                {
                    case (0):
                            <td class="classic-height my-td full">B-@String.Format("{0,2:D2}", j)-@String.Format("{0,2:D2}", i)</td>
                            break;
                        case (1):
                            <td class="classic-height my-td half-full">B-@String.Format("{0,2:D2}", j)-@String.Format("{0,2:D2}", i)</td>
                            break;
                        default:
                            <td class="classic-height my-td empty">B-@String.Format("{0,2:D2}", j)-@String.Format("{0,2:D2}", i)</td>
                            break;
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: Use `@:<tr class="my-tr">` and `@:</tr>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks that helped with those Visual Studio complains but not with the empty page.

Comment: If you try : var x = db.tblShelves
        .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("B"))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.column)
        .ThenBy(x => x.row)
        .ToList()
        ); are you sure there's data being brought back

Comment: @BenJones I can't use the same variable as in the lambda expressions. But I am sure that I am getting the data to the View, because it works without the condition.

Comment: Which condition? the starts with?

Comment: @BenJones Yes, if I leave there just the `<tr>` and `</tr>` without the StartsWith condition it creates the table with one column.

Comment: Why do you need that checking? Can't you just set the start and end `tr` tags before the foreach?

Comment: sorry is this for the headings or the rows?

Comment: can you update the question with what it looks like at the moment and how you'd like it to look :)

Comment: @BenJones Updated the post for how it should look like. The result at the moment it's just blank page, with `<body>` tag from the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: and the code you already have is this for the headings or rows?

Comment: @BenJones What do you mean by heading? I am not using any `<th>` tag. The code should create the whole table, but it just does nothing atm.

Comment: Ok i understand now :) sorry for the confusion, did @html.raw("") work? from the answer below

Comment: @BenJones just used the `@:` which is the shortcut for `@Html.Raw("")` as I wrote in the comments, the Visual studio just stopped complaining, but the page is still blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Tr tag into Html.raw in this format  @Html.Raw("")
and also for closing tr tag i.e   @Html.Raw("")

Edit: Had to use it for the `<td>` tags also.

Comment: Helped with the Visual Studio complains but not with the whole problem.

Comment: Had to use it for the `<td>` tags also.